# oracle group by order by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I have wrote query like:

```
select name,age from people group by name order by age DESC ;
```

I want to select max age for same names .but it gives **"ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"**.

Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: group by needs aggregate functions ...like this: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT name, MAX(age) A FROM poeple GROUP BY name ORDER BY A DESC
```

Comment: Adil , there is the same expression

Comment: Gulnaz, I used alias "A" for MAX(age) and using order by with this alias. I have just one little mistake about DESC. Now I fixed it.